# How to take screen shot in the app to a small frame by coding,iphone

Tags: iphone, image, screenshot

i want to have a screen shot with in the app and then use that image
in the next view.
Is there is a way so we can take screen shot of a view in the app and then use that image.

Many thanks in advance

gagan joshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to do (assuming self is an **UIViewController**):

```
#import < QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h >

...

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

[self.view.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage* screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Now you have the screenshot in the variable **screenshot** and can put it into an UIImageView.

Comment: i added Quartz-core framework, than i #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h > ,it says that this file not found

Comment: how can it possible if you are adding framework correctly? firstly clean and buid.try this.

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

-(UIImage*)getShot
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 460));
    [imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

hope this will help you out for iphone and ipad

Answer (score 2):

capture screen shot of iphone app

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
    -(UIImage*)captureImage
    {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 460));
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return viewImage;
    }
```

Comment: but we need to include instead of import

Comment: me working with Sanjeev and kamarshad, they told me they are your friends, Thanks dude...